# plt.savefig stops working when called from another file

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a code that works well for bulk data analysis and plotting. But now i'm trying to incorporate it into a larger data analysis GUI. I find that when i run my code on its own, all goes well. But when i call it from the main code and run it from a tkinter button, it's not the same. Everything looks the same and it runs smoothly, the only difference is that no files are saved.

i think maybe it's a problem with which window is defined with "____init____"? or something with how i create and destroy Tk() windows within the subcode?

**the stackoverflow text editor uses underscores to make text bold/itallic, so for all cases that double underscores are used to wrap "init" or "main" in python, i had to use four on each side here

my code (saved as SubCode.py):

```py
def AnalysisFunction():
    *does things*
    main = Tk()
    os.chdir(OutputFolder)
    plt.savefig('image.png')
    main.destroy()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AnalysisFuntion()
```

the code i want to add mine into:

```py
import SubCode

class TopLevel(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        *Creates main GUI window*
        MyButton = Button(root, command = self.CallSubCode)
    def CallSubCode(self):
        SubCode.AnalysisFunction()
root = Tk()
main_window = TopLevel(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Any ideas why the subcode alone can save figures but it cannot when called by the larger GUI? FYI, it still creates all variables correctly when running through the larger GUI.

Comment: Do you really have 4 underscores on each side of `__init__`?

Comment: no, as stated in my question. only 2 on each side in the code. if i type two on each side here, the stackoverflow text editor makes the text within __bold__ and removed the underscores. (one underscore = _itallics_, three underscores = ___bold itallics___) try it yourself!

Comment: I think the problem could be you creating two separate instances of `Tk`. They cannot communicate between one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out, I had to put the whole SubCode within a class structure, then call it as its own Toplevel app. I think otherwise the plt.savefig command doesn't know which Tkinter window it is working with, and tries to find data in the "host" window, not the one which is handling the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just save the image in SubCode.py without creating a tkinter window. i.e

```
def AnalysisFunction():
    *does things*
    os.chdir(OutputFolder)
    plt.savefig('image.png')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AnalysisFuntion()
```

Comment: this is a good thought! but on both levels, there is a GUI element that is fairly necessary. perhaps if i make the whole SubCode into a class with its own ____init____ and run it as a class, then it will be it's own thing? i'll try this.